# Why does "docker image build" occupy so much space?

Tags: python, docker

I have a folder that contains code + weights of neural networks + annoy indices and takes approximately 16 GB. The folder also contains a `Dockerfile` and a `requirements.txt`. When I call `docker build .`

- The first step `Sending build context to Docker daemon` takes 16 GB of space
- The step `ADD . /model` takes 32 GB of space. Eventually, it frees 16 GB

Hence, I need at least 48 GB of storage for the build to be successful. Here is my bare-minimum dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.5
WORKDIR /model
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /model
CMD ["python", "deploy.py"]
```

How can I fix this? It appears that the data is getting copied from the current directory multiple times.

Comment: Could you put the data into a volume rather than baked into the image?

Comment: I can provide the data separately along with the image. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't see why `ADD . /model` would take twice the real size of the model folder. 
Can you add the output from these information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker client sends by default the entire directory in which the Dockerfile is located as `build context` to the Docker daemon.

You can either try to eliminate what it is not necessary from the context with a [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) or bring that data into the containers via volumes rather than having it copied at build-time.

Something like this:

```
docker run -v <path-to-your-model-on-the-host-machine>:<path-where-you-want-the-data-inside-the-container> ...
```

Beware that this will allow the container to alter the data from your host machine.

Comment: I am not familiar with volumes. Let's say I have a huge file abc.zip in the same directory as the Dockerfile. If I want to bring it into the container via volumes, how would I do it?

Comment: Go read about volumes. They're a basic Docker concept, lots of googleable information.

Comment: I was updating my answer to provide a simple example while you were writing the comment. @JohnKugelman has a good point: having a thorough lecture about docker volumes will help you a lot in the long run with Docker.